# Disable react-router Link in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to React and got a issue to disable a link covert by a button element.

I tried the following:

```
class ShoppingCartLink extends React.Component {

constructor(){
    super();
    ShoppingCartStore.register(this.refresh.bind(this));

    this.state = {count:0};
    this.item = "items";
    this.linkDisabled = new Boolean(true);
}

refresh(){
    if (ShoppingCartStore.items.length === 0 || ShoppingCartStore.items.length > 1 )
    {
        this.item = "items";
    }
    else
    {
        this.item = "item";
    }

    if (ShoppingCartStore.items.length !== 0)
    {
        this.linkDisabled = false;
    }

    this.setState({count: ShoppingCartStore.items.length});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" disabled = {this.linkDisabled}>
                <Link to="shoppingCart">Shopping Cart: {this.state.count} {this.item}</Link>
            </button>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

By default the Link should be disbaled as long no item is added to the cart. 
I debugged through it and when the constructor is called "linkDisabled" is set to true as well in render(). The problem is that the link is still enabled.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
constructor(){
   super();
   ShoppingCartStore.register(this.refresh.bind(this));

   this.state = {
     count:0,
     linkDisabled: true
   };
}

handleClick(event) {
   if(this.state.linkDisabled) event.preventDefault();
}

refresh(){

   const length = ShoppingCartStore.items.length;

   this.setState({
      count: length,
      linkDisabled: (length === 0)
   });
}

render() {
   const length = ShoppingCartStore.items.length;
   return (<div>
            <Link to="shoppingCart"
                  onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Shopping Cart: {this.state.count} {((length > 0)?"items":"item")}</Link>
    </div>);
}
```

After some refactoring ... Try this ?

Comment: I've tried it, but it's still not working. The link is still enabled when count is 0. But the refactoring helps to make it more clean, thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure that the count is 0 ? and why put `<Link />` in a `<button />` ?

Comment: Yes i'm sure. I debugged through it. The goal is to disable the link. But an `<a />` dosn't got a property disabled. So i tried to use a `<button />`and put the `<link />`in, because `<button />`got a property disabled

Comment: You can preventDefault and stopPropagation of the `<a />` with a css disabled, this will do the same ?

Comment: I never used preventDefault or stopPropagation. Could you explain how it works? As i looked up preventDefault prevents an event from executing his default action, am i right?

Comment: You will see nothing but clicking on the link will do nothing if count is 0

Comment: Cool !, No problem ;)

Comment: Just a little issue with the  pluralization of item/s, because it should work like 0 items, 1 item, 2 items. I fixed it like this: `{((length === 0 || length > 1)?"items":"item")}`

Comment: Really ?? Sorry I'm french but it's strange for me to put a 's' for 0 ^^

Comment: For me as well, but requirement is requirement ^^

Answer (score 2):

There is no "disabled" attribute for anchor tags, and Links are just router aware anchor tags. You can use one of the two things

**1.** Diasble pointer events with css

**REACT Component**

```
constructor(){
   super();
   ShoppingCartStore.register(this.refresh.bind(this));

   this.state = {
     count:0,
     linkDisabled: 'disable-link';
   };
}

refresh(){

   const length = ShoppingCartStore.items.length;
   const classValue =  (length === 0)? 'disable-link': '';
   this.setState({
      count: length,
      linkDisabled: classValue
   });
}

render() {
   const length = ShoppingCartStore.items.length;
   return (<div>
        <button type="button" disabled={this.state.linkDisabled}>
            <Link to="shoppingCart" className={this.state.linkDisabled}>Shopping Cart: {this.state.count} {((length > 0)?"items":"item")}</Link>
        </button>
    </div>);
}
```

**CSS**

```
. disable-link {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**2.**  Make use of event.preventDefault() on click of link if there are no items in the cart

```
constructor(){
   super();
   ShoppingCartStore.register(this.refresh.bind(this));

   this.state = {
     count:0,
     linkDisabled: true
   };
}

refresh(){

   const length = ShoppingCartStore.items.length;

   this.setState({
      count: length,
      linkDisabled: (length !== 0)
   });
}
handleClick = (e) => {
  if(this.state.linkDisabled == true) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
render() {
   const length = ShoppingCartStore.items.length;
   return (<div>
        <button type="button" disabled={this.state.linkDisabled}>
            <Link to="shoppingCart" onClick={this.handleClick}>Shopping Cart: {this.state.count} {((length > 0)?"items":"item")}</Link>
        </button>
    </div>);
}
```

However in both these cases you can access the route with commandline as only pointer events are disabled.

Comment: Actually your className will jsut be `true` or `false` with this code.

Comment: I dont't think so. In refresh function I have given it a class name

Comment: ah my bad haven't seen, sorry.

Comment: No problem :) But you think the above code works right

Comment: I think his problem could come from the Link inside a button ... that make no sense for me.

Comment: Both solutions dosn't work like we want them to. I think @SteevePitis is right and the problem could come from `<button />`

Answer (score 1):

`linkDisabled` does not need to be in state. This opens up possibilities of changing state and forgetting to update `linkDisabled`. It is better to compute it in `render`.

```
class ShoppingCartLink extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        ShoppingCartStore.register(this.refresh.bind(this));

        this.state = {count: 0};
    }

    refresh() {
        this.setState({count: ShoppingCartStore.items.length});
    }

    render() {
        const linkDisabled = this.state.count === 0;
        const item = this.state.count === 1 ? "item" : "items";
        return (
            <div>
                <button type="button" disabled={linkDisabled}>
                    <Link to="shoppingCart">Shopping Cart: {this.state.count} {item}</Link>
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This way, if you ever add more to the component and have to `setState` in a different place, you will not need to worry about duplicating the logic for `linkDisabled` and `item`.

Comment: Good advice, but this.items is undefined. I guess that you want to use state.count at this point. Sadly the link is still enabled and item/items don't response correct.